# Avoid 2-finger scroll to trigger back/forward

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a way to avoid triggering the back/forward in the browser when the user uses a 2-finger scroll (eg: OSX).

just like this:
https://tweetdeck.twitter.com

Answer (score 0):

Mobile devices are notoriously annoying for handling touch events. However, if you return false or preventDefault() on a DOM touch event you will prevent the browser from scrolling/zooming/navigating.

The below example will prevent all touches from executing default behavior; meaning link touches won't register, scrolling won't work etc.

`$("body").on("touchstart", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});`

The following will prevent default functionality of multi touch.

`$("body").on("touchstart", function(e){
    if (e.originalEvent.touches.length == 2) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});`

If you need to allow the user to click links, you would do something along the lines of the following.

`$("body").on("touchstart", function(e){
    if (e.target.tagName != "A") {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});`

Comment: [tag:javascript] tag: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*